Nonexpansiveness of the extragradient method
Let $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be monotone, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \langle x-y, F(x) - F(y)\rangle\geq 0,
\end{equation}
and $L$-Lipschitz continuous, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \|F(x) - F(y)\|\leq L \| x-y\|,
\end{equation}
for some $L>0$. Let $\gamma\in(0,1/L)$ and consider the extragradient operator
\begin{equation}
G : \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n} : x \mapsto x - \gamma F(x - \gamma F(x)).
\end{equation}
My question is: Is the extragradient operator nonexpansive, i.e., $1$-Lipschitz continuous?
I do know that it is quasi-nonexpansive (shown by Korpelevich), i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{n})(\forall x^{*}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}: x^{*} = G (x^{*})) \quad \|G(x) - x^{*}\|\leq \|x-x^{*}\|.
\end{equation}

The answer is no.

Without loss, we can consider $L = 1$. In one dimension, fix $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and suppose it is differentiable with $0 \leq f' \leq 1$ pointwise (so that $f$ is a monotone operator and $1$-Lipschitz).
Fix $\gamma\in(0,1)$. Your question relates to the operator
$$
g_\gamma(x) = x - \gamma f\big(x - \gamma f(x)\big)
$$
Note
$$
g_\gamma'(x) = 1 + \gamma^2 f'\big(x- \gamma f(x)\big)f'(x). 
$$
Hence
$$
M := \sup_{x} g'_\gamma(x) = 1 +  \gamma^2 \Big\{\sup_{x} f'(x - \gamma f(x)) f'(x)\Big\}.
$$
This will be larger than $1$ for any reasonable example (even linear). However, the Lipschitz constant for $g_\gamma$ is precisely the number $M$ given above, which shows that in general you have no hope of non-expansiveness.
